# Import sequelize model in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, electron, sequelize.js

I'm building a CRUD app using electron + vuejs + sequelize, i have used **sequelize init** and configured the **.sequelizerc** as below

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('src/renderer/database/config', 'config.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('src/renderer/database', 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/renderer/database', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/renderer/database', 'migrations')
}
```

Now i'm trying to populate a table with data from the database, I've tried to import the models in many ways, always leading to errors.

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined**

**Component:**

```
var models = require('./../../database/models'); // LINE WITH ERROR

export default {
  name: "user-index",
  data: function() {
    return {
      users: []
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    models.Users.findAll().then(users => {
      //
    });
  },
  components: {},
  methods: {}
};
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem, it is in the models/index.js:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file)); // THIS LINE
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need `require('../../../database/models')` (or `require('../../database/models') `) -- the single dot won't work there

Comment: Yea, i was using without the ./, i added the ./ just in case. But the path is correct.

Comment: From what i have been reading, something like this should work `const User = require("../../database/models").User` but i don't know why it keeps giving me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by changing `path.join` to `path.resolve` and changing this:

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

to

```
for (var modelName in db) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
}
```

in models/index.js file.